# Using global variable in Haskell's function but not as reference

Tags: haskell

is it possible to rewrite this source in Haskell to use function *increase* without reference *x* as argument?

```
increase 0 _ = return ()
increase n x = do
    modifySTRef x (+n)
    increase (n - 1) x

calculation n = runST $ do
    x <- newSTRef 0
    increase n x
    readSTRef x
```

Comment: You should show us what kind of code you would like to write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no[0] way to achieve what you like at the top-level of a source file: there is simply no guarantee on the ordering of "execution" of globals like that. In fact, there's no execution at all (thus the prior scare quotes). You *must* compose `ST` actions together into an execution under `runST` in order to have any of them happen at all.

What this means is that impure bindings—like when you first declare the name of your global variable—must be done in your `runST` block and thus they live at a level below the top-level bindings in a module.

But there's nothing really special about those top-level bindings except that they get exported. You can just build a new "top-level" inside of `runST`:

```
stThread :: ST s Int
stThread = do
  x <- newSTRef

  let increase :: Int -> ST s ()
      increase 0 = return ()
      increase n = do
        modifySTRef x (+n)
        increase (n - 1) x

  increase 10
  increase 20

  readSTRef x

calculation :: Int
calculation = runST stThread
```

[0] Well, no kosher way which doesn't require breaking Haskell semantics. Sometimes people still cheat, but I cannot recommend it in any kind of good faith.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have top-level `ST` references. Having that would break referential transparency. Consider this:

```
x :: STRef s Int
x = magicallyCreateSTRef 0

test1 :: (Int, Int)
test1 = ( runST (modifySTRef x (+1) >> readSTRef x)
        , runST (modifySTRef x (+1) >> readSTRef x) )

test2 :: (Int, Int)
test2 = (y, y)
   where y = runST (modifySTRef x (+1) >> readSTRef x)
```

Now what is the value of `test1`? It could be `(0,1)` or `(1,0)` depending on the evaluation order. This is already a very bad sign that Haskell was broken. To make the point even more clear, `test2` should be clearly equivalent to `test1`, thanks to referential transparency. Still, `test2` can not produce a pair with different values inside.

Hence, you can't have top-level `STRef`s. At most you can have top-level IO references, e.g.

```
x :: IORef Int
x = unsafePerformIO (newIORef 0)
```

As long as the above reference is monomorphic (`IORef Int` and `IORef [Int]` are ok, `IORef [a]` is not), this does not break Haskell's main features, namely type safety and referential transparency. It is still somehow perceived as a little hack, since it uses the forbidden function `unsafePerformIO`, but at least this is a well-known safe use of that.

Why IO references are allowed and ST references are not? Because the `ST` monad has an escaping function `runST` that makes it possible to use monadic value in pure code (e.g. in `test1` and `test2`). Instead, `IO` has no similar `runIO` escaping function.